# Proxy server status capturing

Tags: regex, bash

My goal is to pull the key items for my servers that we are tracking for KPIs. My plan is to run this daily via a cron job and then have it email me once a week to be able to be put in an excel sheet to grab the monthly KPIs. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
server=server1
ports=({8400..8499})

for l in ${ports[@]}
do
    echo "checking on '$l'"
    sp=$(curl -k --silent "https://"$server":"$l"/server-status" | grep -E "Apache Server|Total accesses|CPU Usage|second|uptime" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g')
    echo "$l: $sp" >> kpi.tmp
    grep -v '^$' kpi.tmp > kpi.out
done
```

The output shows like this.

```
8400:
8401: Apache Server Status for server1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  18 days 4 hours 49 minutes 37 seconds
Total accesses: 545 - Total Traffic: 15.2 MB
CPU Usage: u115.57 s48.17 cu0 cs0 - .0104% CPU load
.000347 requests/sec - 10 B/second - 28.6 kB/request
8402: Apache Server Status for server 1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  20 days 2 hours 20 minutes 26 seconds
Total accesses: 33 - Total Traffic: 487 kB
CPU Usage: u118.64 s49.41 cu0 cs0 - .00968% CPU load
1.9e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 14.8 kB/request
8403:
8404:
8405: Apache Server Status for server1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  20 days 2 hours 20 minutes 28 seconds
Total accesses: 35 - Total Traffic: 545 kB
CPU Usage: u133.04 s57.48 cu0 cs0 - .011% CPU load
2.02e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 15.6 kB/request
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to filter the out put to the way i would like it. As you  can see from my desired output, if it does not have any data to not put it in the file, cut some of the info out of the returned data.

I would like my output to look like this:

```
8401:server1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  18 days 4 hours 49 minutes 37 seconds
Total accesses: 545 - Total Traffic: 15.2 MB
CPU Usage: .0104% CPU load
.000347 requests/sec - 10 B/second - 28.6 kB/request
8402: server1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  20 days 2 hours 20 minutes 26 seconds
Total accesses: 33 - Total Traffic: 487 kB
CPU Usage: .00968% CPU load
1.9e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 14.8 kB/request
8405: server1(via x.x.x.x)
Server uptime:  20 days 2 hours 20 minutes 28 seconds
Total accesses: 35 - Total Traffic: 545 kB
CPU Usage: .011% CPU load
2.02e-5 requests/sec - 0 B/second - 15.6 kB/request
```

Comment: `Apache Server Status for ` and `u\d{3}\.\d{2} s\d{2}.\d{2} cu\d cs\d - ` removed from first output except `server 1` in line 7 replaced to `server1`. If line 7 is `server1` originally just use `Apache Server Status for |u\d{3}\.\d{2} s\d{2}.\d{2} cu\d cs\d - ` to find string and replace it to empty.

Comment: IMHO better to use some monitoring ecosystem (e.g.: https://blog.zabbix.com/apache-http-server-monitoring/6972/)